# Using Material Design card div element, but contents within card won't be centered

Tags: css, material-design, html, material-design-lite

I'm trying to add `align="center"` to this card that is from Material Design Lite:

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content" align="center">
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp portfolio-card">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">
      <strong>FOOBAR TEXT</strong>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding it at each one of these divs both all together and separately and the contents with my card still won't center.

This is what it looks like from my end:

[image]

The text in the center are actually MDL buttons that appear to be text until you mouse hover over them and they "pop out" to be a button (just a bell and whistle component). As you can see, "California" isn't quite centered, and quite frankly neither are the buttons (despite the main class element containing `align="center"`).

I am using the MDL Portfolio Template:

[Preview of the template](https://getmdl.io/templates/portfolio/index.html)

[Download link of the template](https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/mdl-template-portfolio.zip)

Here is the CSS as requested:

```
.portfolio-max-width {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.portfolio-header {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(images/header-bg.jpg);
}

.portfolio-header .mdl-layout__header-row {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.mdl-layout__title {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.is-compact .mdl-layout__title span {
  display: none;
}

.portfolio-logo-row {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.is-compact .portfolio-logo-row {
  min-height: auto;
}

.portfolio-logo {
  background: url(images/logo.png) 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto auto 10px;
}

.is-compact .portfolio-logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.portfolio-navigation-row {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 45px;
}

.portfolio-navigation-row  .mdl-navigation {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-navigation-row .mdl-navigation__link {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.portfolio-header .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
    background-color: rgba(197, 197, 197, 0.44);
}

.portfolio-navigation-row .is-active {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.portfolio-navigation-row .is-active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 70%;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255,64,129);
  left: 15%;
}

.portfolio-card .mdl-card__title {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-blog-card-full-bg {
  background: url(images/example-blog03.jpg) center / cover;
}

.portfolio-blog-card-event-bg {
  background: url(images/example-blog05.jpg) center / cover;
}

.portfolio-blog-card-strip-bg {
  background: url(images/example-blog06.jpg) center / cover;
}

.portfolio-blog-card-compact .mdl-card__title {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-blog-card-bg > .mdl-card__actions {
  height: 52px;
  padding: 16px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

img.article-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.portfolio-max-width {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.portfolio-copy {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.no-left-padding{
  padding-left: 0;
}

.no-bottom-padding {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.padding-top {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
}

.portfolio-share-btn {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -4px;
}

.demo-card-event > .mdl-card__actions {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.portfolio-contact .mdl-textfield {
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-contact form {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  background-image: url(images/footer-background.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: align attribute is not supported in HTML5 ..on th other hand use css text-align:center...and to help you more plese but your css and html here

Comment: I will post the CSS in a bit, but I do want to clarify that the align attribute IS IN FACT supported in HTML5. It works in other elements on this same page right now. Are you perhaps referring to how it's not supported in certain elements within HTML5?

Comment: I've added the CSS to the main post. Thank you.

Comment: i will show the css and answer you , align not support in html5 but its work now in most of browser but maybe in future it stoped check here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Comment: add the html too please

Comment: I see what you're saying now, regarding align attribute. My mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125132/discussion-between-mohade-and-nav-bowman).

Answer (score -1):

use the css text-align property

```css
.card
{
  width:270px;
  height:250px;
  padding:2px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #333;
  font-family:Liberation Sans;  
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
     <h4>CALIFORNIA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <strong><p>xxxxxxxxx</p></strong>
    <strong><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p></strong>
    <strong><p>xxxxxxxxxxx</p></strong>
    <strong><p>xxxxxxxxx</p></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```